# is there a way to collect all filepath-information within a blender-file?

Tags: python, blend-files

After a crash of a HD with lots of blend-files I only have files with no names and structure.
I've got a little programm to check if it's a blend-file, made with this class: https://formats.kaitai.io/blender_blend/python.html
so I know, it's a blend-file.
I would like to reconstruct some of the blend-files with filepath information stored in the blend-file which will give me hints eventually, how the folder where it was stored was named and then, perhaps, I can reconstruct it.

there I read, that filepathdes are stored in blend-files:
https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/W2bbbc/?sorting=hot

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `reconstruct some of the blend-files with filepath information stored in the blend-file`? Provide a [blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/) and explain your question in detail.

Comment: In addition to what Karan has said, the blendercommunity thread you referenced is 5 years old. Supposedly there was an edit to it 2 years ago, but I didn't see where it was. Much could have changed since then. If I save a .blend file and open it in either Notepad++ or HxD, the only path info I see is the Blender default file save path, not the path where I actually saved the file. But, it is possible that I missed something. What version of Blender were your files created with?

Comment: Maybe it's a silly idea. 

Yes, that is a very old thread. But that's all I found.

 I appended two of the bunch of files (2800 so far). Very old stuff. So, the blender versions could be very early. I could open every file, of course, and look, what it is.
Reconstruct is somewhat of overstated, perhaps. I only need a clue, what blendfile it could be.
e.g. file000866.blend, v 2.49, has a py-script. Opening, it tells: */home/stefan/daten/....  (unsaved).
investigating in texteditor - oh dear, yes - I found the path-info and more. :)

Ok, I think it was much to early, that I asked here.